# cannot access localhost/phpmyadmin on windows 7 VM

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I try to connect to `localhost/phpmyadmin` I get an error in browser:

> this site cannot be reached

I am running XAMPP on a virtual box windows 7

What I have done so far:

in `config.inc.php` file changed:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

My goal is to create a database on MySQL, but I cannot access phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This is an admin issue, not a programming one. Xampp probably is not running for some reason or you cannot connect to it.

Comment: XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 443
XAMPP MySQL Service is already running on port 3306

this is what I see when I look at XAMPP control panel

Comment: Again, tis is an admin issue. SO is for programming questions. Pls ask your question in he superuser.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in class a friend had a similar problem, don't know if it can apply to you aswell, but in his case there was a port problem because i think it was Skype that occupied the same port that `XAMPP`wanted to use.

In that case you could just change the port of your localhost.